# Proof for sets given constraints

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, set-partition

My question is one from my graph & set theory class that I'm not sure how to solve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Let $\{(A_i, B_i) \mid 1 \leq i \leq h\}$ be a family of pairs of sets satisfying
>
> - $A_i \cap B_i = \varnothing$ for $i = 1, \ldots, h$;
> - $\left|A_i\right| + \left|B_i\right|=k$ for $i=1, \ldots , h$; and
> - for $i\neq j$, at least one of $A_i \cap B_j$ or $A_j \cap B_i$ is nonempty.
>
> Show that $h\leq  2^k$.

Is $h = 2^k$ always attainable?

I tried to use the following theorem: If $A_1, . . . , A_m$ and $B_1, . . . , B_m$ are two sequences of sets such that $A_i \cap B_j = \varnothing$ if and only if $i = j$, then 
 $$ \sum_{i=1}^m{\binom{|A_i|+|B_i|}{|A_i|}}^{-1}\le 1. $$

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance. Regarding your edit, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here.

Comment: Can you describe the theorem you were thinking about using in words?

Comment: Of course, $h = 2^k$ is attainable: Just let the $A_i$ be all $2^k$ subsets of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,k\right\}$, and let $B_i$ be their complements.

Comment: Note that this looks like a version of [Bollobas's skew two families theorem](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/12/25/lovaszs-two-families-theorem/). But not sure if the same approach works.

Comment: These look like Chris Fraser's Math 5707 [2019] problems. You can prove it similarly to [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/sperner.shtml) proof of Sperner's theorem. Construct a bipartite graph with indices $1,\ldots,h$ as the left part, and subsets of $\bigcup_{i=1}^h (A_i \cup B_i)$ as the right part.